# Javascript Regex to replace "=" to "==" without having any special character having it

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the `=` to `==` using the JavaScript on the condition it should not replace if is already as

- `==`
- `>=`
- `<=`
- `=>`
- `=<`

Can anyone help me in this with the explanation. I am trying like below but it was replacing all.

```
text = text.replace(/=/, "==");
```

Input :

`Premium UserId=5||Premium UserId>=2`

Output Needed:

`Premium UserId==5||Premium UserId>=2`

Comment: This seems more like the job for a parser/tokenizer. Is the text being replaced a formal language such as JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```js
var str = 'Premium UserId=5||Premium = UserId>=2',
    re = /([^=><])=([^=><]*?)/g;

console.log(str.replace(re, "$1==$2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this opportunity to learn about [regular expression lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Unfortunately, while JavaScript supports lookahead, it doesn't support lookbehind. Therefore, while the regex `/=(?![>=<])/` will successfully avoid the following matches: `=<` and `=>`, it'll still match everything else.

However, there are ways to [simulate lookbehind in Javascript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript). You can use the following code snippet to achieve what you're trying to do:

```js
var text = 'Premium UserId=5||Premium UserId>=2';
text = text.replace(/([>=<])?=(?![>=<])/g, function($0, $1) {
  return $1 ? $0 : $0 + '=';
}); 
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this? (will not match the very beginning or end of text...)

```
text=text.replace(/([^=><])=([^=><])/g, function (match,p1,p2){ return p1+"=="+p2; });
```

```js
var text = "Premium UserId=5||Premium UserId>=2";

text=text.replace(/([^=><])=([^=><])/g, function (match,p1,p2){ return p1+"=="+p2; });

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```js
var input = "Premium UserId=5||Premium UserId>=2";
var regex = new RegExp( "(?:[0-9a-z\s])=(?![<>])", "gi" );
var output = input.replace( regex , function(match){ return match.charAt(0) + "==" } );
console.log(output);
console.log("Premium UserId =5||Premium UserId>=2".replace( /(?:[0-9a-z\s])=(?![<>])/gi, function(match){ return match.charAt(0) + "==" } ));
console.log("Premium UserId =>5||Premium UserId>=2".replace( /(?:[0-9a-z\s])=(?![<>])/gi, function(match){ return match.charAt(0) + "==" } ));
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this expects that there's a word immediately before the operator (which might as well be but it's not specified in the question). Won't work if the string is "Premium UserId = 5".

Comment: In fact it doesn't work correctly for `=>` and `=<`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var re = /(([^<>=])(={1,1})([^<>=]))/g
var tests = [
 {in: 'Premium UserId=5||Premium UserId>=2', out: 'Premium UserId==5||Premium UserId>=2'},
 {in: 'if (UserId == 5)', out: 'if (UserId == 5)'}
]
tests.forEach(function(test, idx){
  var result = test.in.replace(re, '$2==$4') === test.out
  console.log('test', idx, result)
})
```